# Pass each element of a list to a function that takes multiple arguments in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

For example, if I have

`a=[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],['d','e','f'],[4,5,6]]`

How can I get each element of `a` to be an argument of say, `zip` without having to type

`zip(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using sequence unpacking (thanks to delnan for the name):

```
zip(*a)
```

Comment: Exactly. Btw, this is called sequence unpacking.

Answer (score -1):

Chain()?

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

nm, read it wrong. That won't work.

Comment: Nope.  That will create an iterator over what is essentially all the inner lists added together.

OP is trying to iterate in parallel rather than sequence.

Comment: Yeah realised straight after posting it :(