# How to split list and pass them as separate parameter?

Tags: python, list

Given the definitions:

```
def egg2(arg1, arg2):
    print arg1
    print arg2

argList = ["egg1", "egg2"]
```

How can I simply call `egg2` using the list? I want the same effect as `egg2(argList[0], argList[1])`, but without having to index each element explicitly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass each element of a list to a function that takes multiple arguments in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558593/pass-each-element-of-a-list-to-a-function-that-takes-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass each element of a list to a function that takes multiple arguments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558593/pass-each-element-of-a-list-to-a-function-that-takes-multiple-arguments-in-pytho)

Comment: This version of the question looks better overall than the other one, but there might yet be something better. I don't want to route this to the canonical explaining `*args` in function calls, because this question is the other way around: how to do it, rather than what the syntax means.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
>>> argList = ["egg1", "egg2"]
>>> egg2(*argList)
egg1
egg2
```

You can use *args (arguments) and **kwargs (for keyword arguments) when calling a function.
Have a look at [this blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) on how to use it properly.

Answer (score 15):

There is a special syntax for [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
egg2(*argList)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are maybe better ways, but you can do:

```
argList = ["egg1", "egg2"]
(a, b) = tuple(argList)
egg2(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`arg.split()` does not split the list the way you want because the default separator does not match yours:

```
In [3]: arg
Out[3]: 'egg1, egg2'

In [4]: arg.split()
Out[4]: ['egg1,', 'egg2']

In [5]: arg.split(', ')
Out[5]: ['egg1', 'egg2']
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (emphasis added):

> If sep is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator**, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me that this addresses the fundamental problem, which is that `eggs2` requires two arguments, but any variation on `['egg1', 'egg2'] is a single argument unless preceded by the `*` operator.