# Python: Pass array as separate arguments to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that I can not edit, this function expects 3 arguments

```
def rgb_color(r,g,b):
    print(r,g,b)
```

now I have these values as an array, I can change this var if needed to a list or something

```
black = [0, 0, 0]
```

Is there a way to pass the variable *black* to the function without using

```
black[0], black[1], black[2]
```

something like

```
call_user_function(rgb_color, black)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split list and pass them as separate parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913084/how-to-split-list-and-pass-them-as-separate-parameter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
rgb_color(*black)
```

Comment: I wish this were easier to find