# Get two numpy arrays from an * args parameter function exactly as they were supplied to that function

Tags: python, numpy, arguments, parameter-passing

I a function described as follows (**very simplified version**):

```
def my_func(*args):
    c = other_func(args)
    return c
```

And other_func is defined as:

```
def other_func(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

I have also two numpy arrays:

```
a = [[1.] [2.]]
b = [[2.] [5.]]
```

I want to pass a and b to my_func and retrieve them exactly as I passed them:
The result I want is :

```
c = my_func(a, b)
```

With :

```
c = [[3.] [7.]]
```

But when I call my_func like above, I get this error:

```
TypeError: other_func missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I think the problem is that my_func is not able to unpack the data.
I looked at an almost similar topic (link below) but It doesn't help me enough to fix my problem. Also, I don't want to use a Loop, it will not be practical for my work.

Link : [How to split list and pass them as separate parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913084/how-to-split-list-and-pass-them-as-separate-parameter)

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **you are passing a single argument**. It is up to **you** to unpack the arguments, you need to use `_1, _2 = other_func(*args)`

Comment: `other_func` takes two arguments; that's what  the function definition specifies.  You have to give two, either as `a,b` tuple or with the `*args` unpacking.  With `a+b`, the arguments could be scalars or arrays (or even lists).  In the real case, are there constraints on those arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
c = other_func(args)
```

to

```
c = other_func(*args)
```

Comment: This won't work as it will add together the two arrays not add together the items within each array

Comment: What do you mean by "add together"? `args` is a tuple, `*args` unpacks it into the two original arguments passed to `my_func`, to pass on to `other_func`.

Comment: @narutoArea51 it absolutely *does* work. If you say it doesn't work then you must demonstrate how with a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just edited my post to the original problem. If you copy and paste the code and run it, you will see that it does not give the expected result.

Comment: @narutoArea51 I'm assuming because you eventually accepted this answer, that in fact, it *does work*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't realise adding two np arrays added the numbers within them I thought it would work like a normal list where it just appends the items from one onto the other so [1, 2, 2, 5]. But yes, this does work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, you're right. It works, but a bit oddly. The data is processed as mentioned by Lecdi just above.

Answer (score 2):

Given these 2 (2,1) arrays, `a+b` produces what you want:

```
In [776]: a = np.array([[1.], [2.]])
     ...: b = np.array([[2.], [5.]])
In [777]: a+b
Out[777]: 
array([[3.],
       [7.]])
In [778]: def my_func(a,b):
     ...:     return a+b
     ...: 
In [779]: my_func(a,b)
Out[779]: 
array([[3.],
       [7.]])
```

There is a certain ambiguity, since a matrix formed from them is symmetric

```
In [780]: np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)
Out[780]: 
array([[1., 2.],
       [2., 5.]])
```

Adding rows or columns both produce the [3,7] values.

Overall your question is poorly specified

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over the `args` list and unpack and input each array separately into `other_func` like this:

```
results = []
for arg in args:
    results.append(other_func(*arg))
```

Comment: Yes but I dont want to use for loop.

Comment: In my actual function, I want to be able to pass any number of arguments and let the function pass them to the second function exactly as I passed them to the first without having to go through a loop. Otherwise my code becomes outdated and impractical. But I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: The example I gave is a toy case. In reality, my other_func function can take different number of variables and its role is not a simple addition but a much more complex calculation.

Comment: This won't work, this will throw the exact same error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just retested this and it works fine...

Comment: This *happens* to work for arrays of length exactly 2