# How to neatly pass each item of a Python list to a function and update the list (or create a new one)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iteration, sequence

Given a list of `floats` **spendList**, I want to apply `round()` to each item, and either update the list in place with the rounded values, or create a new list.

I'm imagining this employing list comprehension to create the new list (if the original can't be overwritten), but what about the passing of each item to the `round()`?

I discovered sequence unpacking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558606/1389110) so tried:

```
round(*spendList,2)
```

and got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-289-503a7651d08c> in <module>()
----> 1 round(*spendList)

TypeError: round() takes at most 2 arguments (56 given)
```

So surmising that `round` was trying to round each item in the list, I tried:

```
[i for i in round(*spendList[i],2)]
```

and got:

```
In [293]: [i for i in round(*spendList[i],2)]
  File "<ipython-input-293-956fc86bcec0>", line 1
    [i for i in round(*spendList[i],2)]
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

Can sequence unpacking even be used here? If not, how can this be achieved?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map ...or a list comprehension as you say

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Comment: @Anentropic thanks, works. I needed to add a `lambda` to allow for the arguments that `round()` takes though: `map(lambda x: round(x,2), spendList)`. Can map handle these arguments itself somehow?

Comment: `spendList[:] = [round(1,2) for i in spendList]` will update the original object, you can also use a regular for loop using enumerate

Comment: @Pyderman yes you need the lambda like you did, or a generic way of adding a static argument to function call is https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) the wrong way around:

```
[i for i in round(*spendList[i],2)]
```

should be:

```
[round(i, 2) for i in spendList]
```

You want to iterate over `spendList`, and apply `round` to each item in it. There's no need for `*` (*"splat"*) unpacking here; that's generally only needed for functions that take an arbitrary number of positional arguments (and, per the error message, `round` only takes two).

Comment: The most elegant solution. Had never before considered starting off a list comprehension with a function call. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` function for this -

```
>>> lst = [1.43223, 1.232 , 5.4343, 4.3233]
>>> lst1 = map(lambda x: round(x,2) , lst)
>>> lst1
[1.43, 1.23, 5.43, 4.32]
```

For Python 3.x , you need to use `list(map(...))` as in Python 3.x `map` returns an iterator not a list.

Comment: Note that, per [the introduction of the `map` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) (emphasis mine): *"a quick fix is to wrap `map()` in `list()`, e.g. `list(map(...))`, **but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension**"*.

Comment: And in particular, if you're using a lambda with `map` then the list comprehension is likely to be more readable. `[round(x,2) for x in lst]`

Comment: @Anand I had just figured out that I needed `lamdba` or something similar to allow for the rounding; you just beat me to adding my a comment thereof. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could still use the list comprehension you talked aobut, just this way:

```
list = [1.1234, 4.556567645, 6.756756756, 8.45345345]
new_list = [round(i, 2) for i in list]
```

new_list will be:
[1.12, 4.56, 6.76, 8.45]